# How to draw lines using UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

I can draw lines using CGContext. How to draw lines with the same coordinates using UIView? I want to move lines in the future, so that I need to use UIView.

```
func DrawLine()
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let lineWidth : CGFloat = 5

    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: 100))
    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)
    context?.strokePath()

    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: 100))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: 700))
    context?.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
override func viewDidLoad() 
{        
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DrawLine()
}
```

Comment: you could just do the drawing in an overriden `func draw(_ rect: CGRect)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a `CAShapeLayer` to a `UIView`

   ```
   let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
   view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
   ```
2. set the shapelayer path to the lines

   ```
   shapeLayer.path = // some CGPath you create
   ```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40556796/3937 for how to make a CGPath with lines.

Comment: I want to move line. I use TouchMoved. This is code:
line.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: line.frame.origin.x, y: location.y)
My line is shifted relative to location of finger for about 100 pixels.
Why does it happen?

Comment: Add the relevant code (formatted correctly) to a new question.  The main thing -- show the code for getting the touch point coordinates.  What view is it in? If not the view that is drawing, you need to translate the coordinates.  The PATH coordinates are relative to the view it is in